# Automated Web Test Server Deployment

Tags: java, tomcat, web, deployment, automation

I've been reading quite a bit about automating server deployment but most of what I've been reading is complex for me to understand right now. I can't seem to incorporate our development process to what the online materials is discussing to me. Please help.

What I want is to automate a certain part of my daily task as a tester.
This is to deploy my own test server for me to conduct testing.

The process goes on like this:

1. I will pull the changes made by our devs from bitbucket
2. Generate a war file from it
3. Then deploy this war file using tomcat (catalina.bat)

Do you guys have any idea how can I automate this process?

I am also open for revamping the current deployment process that I am doing if there's a better approach to do it.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

One popular approach could be to configure a [jenkins](https://jenkins.io/) instance [to pull the changes from bitbucket](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Bitbucket+pullrequest+builder+plugin).

Then jenkins could [generate a WAR file](http://paxcel.net/blog/automation-of-warear-deployment-using-jenkins/) and [deploy it](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jenkins/jenkins_automated_deployment.htm) to your tomcat instance.

An extra step is to [add some unit tests](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jenkins/jenkins_unit_testing.htm) in the process.